# Need help in my program in eclipse

Tags: android

```
public void click(View view) {

    String one = "one";
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String entered_text = et.getText().toString();

    if(et.getText().toString() == one){

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText("Correct!");
    }

    else {

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(one+entered_text);   }
    }
```

This is a code snippet extracted from my program, I didn't post the whole program because it wasn't necessary, as the program runs fine without any runtime exceptions.

So, the program when executed on Eclipse doesn't show any errors and runs fine, but when run the, `if` condition `et.getText().toString() == "one"` always returns false even when the `entered_text` is `one` i.e.; it never prints "correct!" and the code always prints "one+entered_text" that is the statement in the else clause. And the interesting point is, if you enter `one` the output will be `oneone`, that is the else statement.

Please help me where I went wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `if (myString.equals("some string"))`, not the **==** operator, for string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know where my mind was. Eezy peezy

Comment: Hey, can you help me with how to use string in switch. I'm using java 6 on eclipse. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `how to use string in switch. I'm using java 6 on eclipse` The string comparison in switch has been introduced with Java **7**, which is **partially supported**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(et.getText().toString().equals(one)){
```

instead of

```
if(et.getText().toString() == one){
```

Comment: @SurajKamble:- You are welcome. Do accept this as an answer if that helped you. The right tick mark(click it and it will go green)

Answer (score 0):

the better way is to compare string like  et.getText().toString().equals("one"); 
also do  et.getText().toString().trim().equals("one"); to avoid spaces error